# How to make an Alert in Splunk?

Tags: splunk

I want to make an Alert in Splunk when the sum is greater than 1000. 
So if the sum is greater than 1000, I want to send an email to xyz.

I can't select the right opportunity in the Splunk Alert menu.

Answer (score 3):

Add `| where sum>1000` to your query.  Then have the alert trigger when the number of events is not zero.